# how to handle java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException exception?

Tags: java, error-handling, executionexception

Some part of my code is throwing java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException exception.
How can I handle this? Can I use throws clause? I am a bit new to java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to handle the exception, things are pretty straightforward.

```
   public void exceptionFix1() {
       try {
           //code that throws the exception
       } catch (ExecutionException e) {
           //what to do when it throws the exception
       }
   }

   public void exceptionFix2() throws ExecutionException {
       //code that throws the exception
   }
```

Keep in mind that the second example will have to be enclosed in a `try-catch` block somewhere up your execution hierarchy.

If you're looking to fix the exception, we'll have to see more of your code.

Answer (score 17):

It depends on how mission critical your `Future` was for how to handle it. The truth is you shouldn't ever get one. You only ever get this exception if something was thrown by the code executed in your `Future` that wasn't handled.

When you `catch(ExecutionException e)` you should be able to use `e.getCause()` to determine what happened in your `Future`.

Ideally, your exception doesn't bubble up to the surface like this, but rather is handled directly in your `Future`.

Answer (score 5):

You should investigate and handle the cause of your ExecutionException.

One possibility, described in "Java Concurrency in Action" book, is to create `launderThrowable` method that take care of unwrapping generic `ExecutionExceptions`

```
void launderThrowable ( final Throwable ex )
{
    if ( ex instanceof ExecutionException )
    {
        Throwable cause = ex.getCause( );

        if ( cause instanceof RuntimeException )
        {
            // Do not handle RuntimeExceptions
            throw cause;
        }

        if ( cause instanceof MyException )
        {
            // Intelligent handling of MyException
        }

        ...
    }

    ...
}
```